# Convert multiple SQL JOINs to Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to convert this SQL query:

```
select t.id,t.name as table_name,r.name as room_name,iif(c.id is null ,0,1) as opened,
 from gs_pos_t t
inner join gs_pos_r r on t.id_r=r.id
left join gs_pos_c c on t.id=c.id_t
left join gs_pos_pz p on c.id=p.id_c
 where c.open_date is not null
 group by 1,2,3,4
```

I need to select all tables from all rooms and the status if there are opened sales on them,in this case the sum of current opened sale

I've tried with no luck something like this:

```
        db.GS_POS_t.Join(
                      db.GS_POS_r,
                      t => t.ID_r,
                      r => r.ID,
                   (tables, rooms) => new {tables,rooms})
               .GroupJoin(
                     db.GS_POS_C
                       .GroupJoin(
                           db.GS_POS_C_PZ,
                           c => c.ID,
                           p => p.ID_C,
                           (sales, p) => new { sales, s_detail= p.DefaultIfEmpty() }
                           )
                           ,
                     mg => mg.tables.ID,
                     cg => cg.sales.ID_t,
                     (tablesrooms, saleswithdetail) => new { tablesrooms, saleswithdetail }
                ).Where(r => r.saleswithdetail.) <=Here !!!!
            );
```

this is the model:

```
GS_POS_T  (tables)
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public short ID_R { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GS_POS_C> GS_POS_C { get; set; }
        public virtual GS_POS_R GS_POS_R { get; set; }
       ...

GS_POS_R (rooms)

        public short ID { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GS_POS_T> GS_POS_T { get; set; }
        ...

GS_POS_C (sales)
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long ID_T { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> OPEN_DATE { get; set; }
        ......    
        public virtual GS_POS_M GS_POS_M { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<GS_POS_C_PZ> GS_POS_C_PZ { get; set; }


GS_POS_C_PZ  (sale details)
        public long ID { get; set; }
        public long ID_C { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> CANT { get; set; }
        public Nullable<decimal> PRICE { get; set; }
        public virtual GS_POS_C GS_POS_C { get; set; }
       ...
```

**PARTIAL SOLUTION**
I got next code that almost works,but 2 problems:

**1**.I can't include in final result ID field from db.GS_POS_C

*ExceptionMessage":"The cast to value type 'System.Int64' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic
 parameter or the query must use a nullable type."*

**2**.I want to convert it to method syntax

```
from t in db.GS_POS_T
        join r in db.GS_POS_R on t.id_r equals r.id //it is inner join statement
        join c in db.GS_POS_C on t.id equals c.id_t  into ct
              from sub1 in ct.DefaultIfEmpty()  //it is left join statement
        join p in db.GS_POS_PZ on sub1.id equals p.id_c into psub1
              from sub2 in psub1.DefaultIfEmpty() //it is left join statement
              where t.activ == 1
        select new { t.id, t.name, rname = r.name,  sub2.cant, sub2.price } into x
        group x by new { id = x.id, name = x.name, rname = x.rname } into g
        select new
        {
            tid = g.Key.id,
            tname = g.Key.name,
            rname = g.Key.rname,
            sumpcantpprice = g.Sum(abc => abc.price * abc.cant)
        };
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: how do your models look like?

Comment: Hi,I've added in first post

Comment: You should use the navigation properties (like `GS_POS_T`), not join.

Answer (score 1):

for the left outer join in linq you can use this syntax:

```
DefaultIfEmpty(new Model())
```

So, this may give you an idea, i wrote it quickly on the fly, so it may not wrok from the first try. I don't know your models, so replace the models in the linq statement and give it a try:

```
    var result = from t in gs_pos_t

                        join r in gs_pos_r on t.id_r equals r.id

                        join c in gs_pos_c on t.id equals c.id_t into firstList from lt1 in firstList.DefaultIfEmpty(new Model1())

                        join p in gs_pos_pz onc.id equals p.id_c into secondList from lt2 in secondList.DefaultIfEmpty(new Model2())

                        where c.open_date != null

                        select new
                        {
                            t.id,
                            t.name,
                            r.name,
                            lt1.id == null ? 0 : 1
                        };
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi,thanks for your aswer, I'm using method syntax and tried .DefaultIfEmpty  but the same problem  on last  .GroupJoin I can't select fields from t.cgcom when I press dot

Comment: can you please paste the code that you wrote with DefaultIfEmpty ?

Comment: I've updated code in first post,I'm not able to select any field from saleswithdetail :  .Where(r => r.saleswithdetail. <=Here !!!!

Comment: my problem In simple words: using .Join over T1 and T2 gives me the option to select fields name from T1 or T2  when using at last  .Where()   but using .GroupJoin give me only fields from T1,what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I've added to first post a partial solution